# Creating the correct SQL query has me seriously stumped

Tags: sql

I have written a Visual Studio database application, that among other things queries the database table for "specific rows" of data.

The code segment that follows has the queries I have tried (and failed) to return records from a MS Access database. The queries that are remarked out are tried and failed ones, the first 2 in red was working and then for no apparent reason stopped working. The queries that are in red are the one that I require to retrieve the correct recordset.

The one that I am currently using contains the "like" keyword which will return the rows that I am seeking plus numerious others which are not relevant to my use.

```
Dim sql As String
Dim myConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Earthquakes.accdb"

Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(myConnectionString)

conn.Open()
    'sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes WHERE swarm_num = '" & num2 & "'"
    'sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes ORDER BY swarm_num" ' WHERE swarm_num = '" & num2 & " ' "
    'sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes WHERE swarm_num = '" & TextBox3.Text.TrimStart & "'"
    sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes WHERE swarm_num like '%" & TextBox3.Text.TrimStart & "%'"
    ''sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes WHERE swarm_num = '" & TextBox3.Text.TrimStart & "'"
    'sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes" 'WHERE swarm_num = '" & num2 & " ' "
    ' string queryString = "SELECT User_ID, UserName FROM tblUsers WHERE " + filter + ";";
    Dim cmd As String = sql
    'Stop
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim EarthquakeTableAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)

    EarthquakeTableAdapter.Fill(ds, "tblEarthquakes") 'it'll autocreate columns etc

    ' the following 3 lines were the key to assigning the retrived records(DataSet) to DataGridView(dgvLocationCode2)
    dgvLocationCode2.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    dgvLocationCode2.DataSource = ds
    dgvLocationCode2.DataMember = "tblEarthquakes"


    conn.Close()

    'Stop
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Row = dgvLocationCode.CurrentCell.RowIndex

    x = dgvLocationCode.Rows(Row).Cells(2).Value

    Dim i As Integer

    i = dgvLocationCode.CurrentRow.Index
    TextBox1.Text = dgvLocationCode.Item(0, i).Value
    TextBox2.Text = dgvLocationCode.Item(1, i).Value
    TextBox3.Text = dgvLocationCode.Item(2, i).Value
```

---

Can anyone see how this query can be written so the "WHERE =" part of the query is executed.

Any help would be most welcome.

```
    'sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes WHERE swarm_num = '" & num2 & "'"
    'sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes ORDER BY swarm_num" ' WHERE swarm_num = '" & num2 & " ' "
    'sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes WHERE swarm_num = '" & TextBox3.Text.TrimStart & "'"
    sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes WHERE swarm_num like '%" & TextBox3.Text.TrimStart & "%'"
    ''sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes WHERE swarm_num = '" & TextBox3.Text.TrimStart & "'"
    'sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes" 'WHERE swarm_num = '" & num2 & " ' "
```

The first queries returned the correct recordset. The others failed to retrieve any records.

The one with the "like" keyword is what I am currently using.

Comment: Hi - I would do the following: 1) Write and execute the query directly on your DB so you can be sure of the correct syntax 2) Get your code to write out the SQL statement it is going to execute - rather than executing it 3) Compare the working SQL from 1 to the output of 2 and then adjust your code until they match

Comment: Thanks NickW for your reply and you are correct, my problem is syntactical. I cannot count the number of ways I have attempted to debug this problem, not just with the queries I listed. I only came to the "like" condition through scouring the web and coming to this solution (on stackflow) here....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561090/finding-records-in-a-database-using-a-textbox-and-search-button-in-vb-net. I think my next avenue is to attempt to use another SQL keyword to narrow the focus of my query.  Once again thank you and if anything else comes to mind, please let me know.

Comment: Print out the resulting SQL statement string and try it, your problem is probably that the syntax youre creating is wrong (syntax issue) - one thing I can think of is maybe use UPPER(column) LIKE UPPER( textbox ) to eliminate any case issues. The other thing is that sometimes invisible characters or spaces can leak its way through the text box

Comment: In these 2 tried SQLs I used the textbox method .trimstart which trims leading spaces, perhaps I should try .trimall. ...        'sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes WHERE swarm_num = '" & TextBox3.Text.TrimStart & "'"
        sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes WHERE swarm_num like '%" & TextBox3.Text.TrimStart & "%'"
What do you mean by leak through the textbox value?

Comment: I just wanted to thank you here for pushing me to find the solution to my issue, which I finally did yesterday. Although var num2 had been assigned the value of textbox3 earlier it's value was not being seen in the query.  I needed to use the actual textbox3 in the query.           sql = "SELECT ID, eventId, event, swarm_num, date_time, latitude, longitude, magnitude, region FROM tblEarthquakes  WHERE swarm_num = '" & TextBox3.Text.TrimStart & " ' ".  Thanks to all once again